# Java - Retain only the Rest API base URL of a Rest API

Tags: java

Small question regarding how to use java to retain only the base URL of a rest API please.

As input, many strings, all valid rest APIs.

For instance, the inputs:

**https://some-host.com**/v1/someapi

**https://another-host.fr**/api/compute

**https://somewhere.host.com**/public/api/v3/getsomething

I would like to only retain the **bold** part, basically, the https, the : and the slashes, the host name. Everything that comes after the host, I would like to discard it.

Currently, I am trying some kind of string.split based on the / character, then trying to re-concat the arrays, but I have a feeling I am not going to the right direction.

What would be the most appropriate way please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just try `java.net.URL` or `java.net.URI`. They behave pretty similar.

For example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/a/b/c");
url.getProtocol();
url.getHost();
url.getPath();
```

or:

```
URI uri = new URI("http://example.com/a/b/c");
uri.getScheme();
uri.getHost();
uri.getPath();
```

There are several methods in both classes to extract lot's of different parts.

Comment: Learned something new. Thank you